# Get only specific key/values from JSON by key names not all

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have JSON that shows multiple key-value pairs. I'd like to loop through and create a new array with only the key-value pairs I want in order to display them. This is my attempt, but of course, my code is re-writing my array (`$new_array`) to have only one element.

```
 //SAMPLE JSON
 [{"PropertyId":"555","FloorplanId":"555","FloorplanName":"Studio","Beds":"0","Baths":"1.00","AvailabilityURL","UnitTypeMapping":".058500"},{"PropertyId":"666","FloorplanId":"666","FloorplanName":"Studio","Beds":"0","Baths":"1.00","AvailabilityURL","UnitTypeMapping":".058500"}]

 //GET ALL JSON FROM URL
 $json = file_get_contents('<URL>');
 $data = json_decode($json);
 // print_r($data); //ALL keys

 //GET JUST THE KEYS I WANT
 $new_array = array("FloorplanName"=>"","Beds"=>"","Baths"=>"");

 // Create new array
 foreach($data as $item) {
   $new_array['FloorplanName'] = $item->{'FloorplanName'};
   $new_array['Beds'] = $item->{'Beds'};
   $new_array['Baths'] = $item->{'Baths'};
 }

 //loop over $new_array
 foreach($new_array as $item) {
   $item->{'FloorplanName'};
   $item->{'Beds'};
   $item->{'Baths'};
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you set associative keys on `$new_array` and overwrite your data each time through your `foreach` loop. Instead, you need to add an item (a sub-array) to `$new_array` and assign the data to the sub-array.

Instead of this:

```
//GET JUST THE KEYS I WANT
$new_array = array("FloorplanName"=>"","Beds"=>"","Baths"=>"");

// access property of object in array
 foreach($data as $item) {
   $new_array['FloorplanName'] = $item->{'FloorplanName'};
   $new_array['Beds'] = $item->{'Beds'};
   $new_array['Baths'] = $item->{'Baths'};
 }
```

You need

```
$new_array = array(); // this array should be empty

// access property of object in array
foreach($data as $item) {
  $new_array[] = array(
    'FloorplanName' => $item->{'FloorplanName'},
    'Beds' => $item->{'Beds'},
    'Baths' => $item->{'Baths'},
  );
}
```

Also, to loop through the new array, you need to change your final loop:

```
//loop over $new_array
foreach($new_array as $item) {
  echo $item['FloorplanName'];
  echo $item['Beds'];
  echo $item['Baths'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's it!

Comment: @Omar Glad to help; please remember to accept the answer and upvote if you found it helpful! ;)

Comment: How would I loop through the new_array and just display all the values, not key names

Comment: @Omar Please see my edit. You need to use `$item['...']`, not `$item->{'...'}`, and just `echo` whatever you need.